# Why doesn't acetic acid affect the formation of beta-nitroamine in nitro-Mannich reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In a nitro-Mannich reaction, if we deprotonate a nitroalkane species with a strong base, then add acetic acid followed by an imine species, the reaction still proceeds giving the $\beta$-nitroamine.

Why is that the case and why wouldn’t we get protonation of the nitro anion species hindering a subsequent reaction with the imine?